# How to transform list from database into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have a following problem. My database returns a list:

```
[Order(id=22617, frm=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 8, 0), to=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 10, 0), loc=Location(lat=14.491272455461, lng=50.130463596998), address='Makedonska 619/11, Praha', duration=600), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 11, 38, 46), Order(id=22615, frm=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 8, 0), to=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 14, 0), loc=Location(lat=14.681866313487, lng=50.007439571346), address='Výhledová 256, Říčany', duration=600), datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 10, 33, 33)]
```

Every output from the database is a type `routes_data_loading.data_structures.Order` and `datetime.datetime`. I would like to save it as a pandas dataframe.

Desired output for the first row is:

```
id;frm;to;lat;lng;address;duration;time
22617;2020-06-01 08:00;2020-06-01 10:00;14.491272455461;50.130463596998;Makedonska 619/11, Praha;600;2020-06-01 11:38:46
```

Semicolumn stands for a new column. Note that the last column `time` has to be created, because its name is not in the original list.

Can you help me how to convert this list into pandas df, please? I know how to convert simple list into df, but not this complicated one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try if `lst[0].__dict__` return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this without guarantee of success:

```
data = []
for order, time in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]):
    data.append({'id': order.id, 'frm': order.frm, 'to': order.to,
                 'lat': order.loc.lat, 'lng': order.loc.lng,
                 'address': order.address, 'duration': order.duration, 
                 'time': time})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      id                 frm                  to        lat        lng                   address  duration                time
0  22617 2020-06-01 08:00:00 2020-06-01 10:00:00  14.491272  50.130464  Makedonska 619/11, Praha       600 2020-06-01 11:38:46
1  22615 2020-06-01 08:00:00 2020-06-01 14:00:00  14.681866  50.007440     Výhledová 256, Říčany       600 2020-06-01 10:33:33
```

How do I setup:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import datetime

Order = namedtuple('Order', ['id', 'frm', 'to', 'loc', 'address', 'duration'])
Location = namedtuple('Location', ['lat', 'lng'])

lst = [Order(id=22617, frm=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 8, 0), to=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 10, 0), loc=Location(lat=14.491272455461, lng=50.130463596998), address='Makedonska 619/11, Praha', duration=600),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 11, 38, 46),
       Order(id=22615, frm=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 8, 0), to=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 14, 0), loc=Location(lat=14.681866313487, lng=50.007439571346), address='Výhledová 256, Říčany', duration=600),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 1, 10, 33, 33)]
```

Comment: works fine, thanks!

Comment: Wow. Glad to read that. I was not confidence in my answer :) Thanks for your support!